# How can I execute javascript in a frame in the browser like pasting "javascript:" into the url bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I can paste javascript into the URL bar of Firefox or enter it in the Firebug console but how do I do it when the target is a frame inside the parent webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your script with `frames[x]`, where `x` is the index of the frame.
Compare:

```
document.write("foo");
```

with:

```
frames[0].document.write("bar");
```